# ffmpeg: missing streams when piping to file from stdout

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm trying to use `ffmpeg` to take an input `mp3` audio file (which contains an audio source and video source) from `stdin`, make modifications, and then send the `mp3` to `stdout`. However, upon inspection of the audio after saving the stream from `stdout`, the file stream is missing the video source even though `ffmpeg` output states it is a part of the `output` sent to `stdout`.

For example, here's the command I'm running with modifications removed (I'm using `node fluent ffmpeg` but here's the converted command)

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -f mp3 -map 0 pipe:1
```

I added the `-map 0` to ensure all `Sources` are passed to the output.

After running, I receive the following output:

```
 ffmpeg version 4.3.4-0+deb11u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
   built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
   configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --arch=arm64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
   libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
   libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
   libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
   libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
   libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
   libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
   libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
   libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
 Input #0, mp3, from 'pipe:0':
   Metadata:
    #REMOVED METADATA TO SHORTEN
   Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
     Stream #0:1: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1500x1500 [SAR 11811:11811 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
     Metadata:
       title           : cover
       comment         : Cover (front)
 Stream mapping:
   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (mp3float) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (png (native) -> png (native))
 [mp3 @ 0xaaaae0fbb180] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
 Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
 Output #0, mp3, to 'pipe:1':
   Metadata:
    # REMOVED METADATA TO SHORTEN
     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
     Metadata:
       encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libmp3lame
     Stream #0:1: Video: png, rgb24(progressive), 1500x1500 [SAR 11811:11811 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
     Metadata:
       title           : cover
       comment         : Cover (front)
       encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 png
 frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:31.32 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=62.6x
 frame=    1 fps=1.0 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:01:08.31 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=68.3x
 frame=    1 fps=0.7 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:01:46.21 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=70.8x
 frame=    1 fps=0.5 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:02:24.19 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=72.1x
 frame=    1 fps=0.4 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:03:04.11 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=73.6x
 frame=    1 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 Lsize=    5618kB time=00:03:35.09 bitrate= 213.9kbits/s speed=72.8x
 video:2256kB audio:3361kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.009597%
```

Everything looks good so far! As you can see, the output correctly maps `Stream #0:0 (audio)` and `Stream #0:1 (album art)` to `Output #0`. which is my `stdout`, yea?

So my output stream `pipe:1` should contain both the audio and video streams, correct? However, when I pipe that stream to an output file and run `ffprobe`, I see the following:

```
ffprobe version 5.0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.0.1_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
[mp3 @ 0x11d604890] Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mp3float @ 0x11d604c50] Header missing
    Last message repeated 286 times
[mp3 @ 0x11d604890] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '/Users/jordan/Downloads/ODESZA-Wide.mp3':
  Duration: 00:04:32.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
```

The output claims that there's a low score for `mp3` detection, missing a header, and also `Stream #0:1 (the album art)` is completely missing from `Input #0` even though it was a part of the `Output #0` which should be sent to the `stdout`.

Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how piping streams work? When piping to an output file, can it only write a single stream like `Stream #0:0` or should it being writing the entire `Stream #0:0 AND Stream #0:1` since that is composition of the `mp3` file?

If I run the same command, but write directly to file instead of `stdout`, like this:

`ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -f mp3 -map 0 out.mp3`

it contains both streams, so clearly this has to do with how piping streams work, right?

Thank you!

Comment: Try : `ffmpeg -f mp3 -i pipe:0 -map 0 -c copy -f nut pipe:1` and then `ffmpeg -f nut -i pipe:0 -map 0 -c copy -id3v2_version 3 -f mp3 out.mp3`

Comment: @JordanLewallen I am not sure, but I think FFmpeg is not writing the Cover to stdout pipe because the output pipe is "**non-seekable**" (when writing to a file we can seek forward and backward, but a pipe is a FIFO). I think the Cover is actually written to the file, but not "marked" correctly.

Comment: The example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710992/how-to-add-album-art-with-ffmpeg) is also not working with an output pipe. The output is not valid: `ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -i test.png -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" -f mp3 pipe: > out2.mp3`

Comment: There is an explanation and a partial solution in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620528/metadata-in-mp3-not-working-when-piping-from-ffmpeg-with-album-art).